# How can i open activity from the notification in android?

Tags: android, notifications, broadcast

I am new to notifications.I succefully generated notification but i want to write the click event for the notification. If i click the notification i want to open one class in my project. That is my task.

For the general pending intent i will open the activity but my task is every 30 mints the broadcast is running once. And that will get notification.

I wrote the code but that is not opened my application when i click.please look my code once.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        sendBroadcastMethod(context);
    }
    private void sendBroadcastMethod(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Alaram", "Alarm Started");
    }
}
```

**AlarmReceiver**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    Context context2;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context2 = context;
        callNotification();
    }

    private void callNotification() 
    {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context2.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context2);

        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("My notification");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Hello World!");


        mNotificationManager.notify(0,mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

It displays notification perfectly but where can i write click operation for my notification. If i write the intent in receiver class builder that will not accept the receiver intent formation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your callNotification() method

```
Intent in = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);     
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    0, in, 0);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this block to your `callNotification` method;

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this.context2, MainActivity.class); 
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.context2, 0, notificationIntent,   
       PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  

mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

You can add flags to that PendingIntent. For example in this example a flag added to update current activity.
Good luck.

Comment: Are you sure about your BroadcastReceiver is working?